# "Potential Infinite Loop" Confusion

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, infinite-loop, array-splice

When I run the below function I get this error:

"Error: Potential infinite loop."

The problem seems to be the "0" I use in the splice method, because when I change it to any other number (1 - 9) I don't get this error.

I'm not sure how this would create an infinite loop.

Is the "0" I'm using in the splice method getting confused with "i" or something?

Help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

```
function spinalCase(str) {
  var array = str.split("");
  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] !== array[i].toLowerCase()) {
      array.splice(i, 0, " ");
    }
  }
  return array;
}
spinalCase('AllThe-small Things');
```

Comment: Read about syntax of [__`Array#splice`__](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: what is the purpose of `array.splice(i, 0, " ");` do you want to replace current item with space?

Comment: Your code inserts new elements into the array, which makes the `array.length` bigger.

Comment: @nnnnnn Ah, thank you, I'll go ahead an make a change and see if the error goes away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array.splice(i, 0, " ");` says to insert a new element at the current `i` index. Which means the item that was at `i` gets pushed up to be at `i + 1`. So then on the next iteration of the loop you process that same item again, resulting in another insert, etc., forever.

You could increment `i` an extra time inside the `if` block, but I prefer to loop *backwards*:

```js
function spinalCase(str) {
  var array = str.split("");
  for (i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (array[i] !== array[i].toLowerCase()) {
      array.splice(i, 0, " ");
    }
  }
  return array;
}
console.log(spinalCase('AllThe-small Things'));
```

Comment: Aha! Thanks. The main thing I missed was the fact that the current element at index "i" gets bumped up one, when using my old for-loop syntax. 

Thanks Again!